# Navigation bar hover customized effect

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a navigation bar whose hover effect on the items is similar to the one on http://mwitosacco.coop/. which css styles can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the default Bootstrap style using your own style and use the browser inspector to copy the style from their site.

To overwrite Bootstrap style, you need to make sure your style is loaded later than the default one so that your style property overtake the default Boostrap style.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it using css,the basic styling would be:

```css
ul>li>a:hover{
  border: 2px solid #2eb2ff;
}
```

use your class names from the html of your navbar and put them with the ul,li,a pseudo elements css respectively

Comment: I am happy for you that it worked, welcome. please give a up vote to my answer

Comment: How can I achieve the same effect on wordpress

Comment: sorry noob in wordpress